# devstack multi node installation

Tags: openstack

I have 3 nodes which i am using for multi node setup. I am thinking of following the below structure

Controller: keystone, horizon, g-reg, g-api, n-api, n-crt, n-sch, n-cond, n-cauth, n-obj, n-novnc, n-xvnc, c-api, c-sch (this node will have mysql and rabbitmq as well)

Network: q-svc, q-agt, q-dhcp, q-l3, q-meta, quantum

Compute: n-cpu, c-vol

I have a few questions. 1. In Compute node, do i need to keep n-api? Also what else is needed apart from n-api and c-vol? Is q-agt needed in compute? 2. Will i need c-api along with c-vol? Does compute node need rabbit mq installed?

Answer (score 0):

Q1)

You don't want the nova-api on the compute nodes generally.  It's better on the controller.

Nova api makes use of pasted hard system credentials and you don't want that paste file exposed on any node that a user may compromise with a hypervisor escape.

nova-compute and nova-volume is all you probably need.  they do communicate with the scheduler over rabbitmq so make sure that's working =P

Q2)

You don't NEED cinder to run an openstack cloud, though I see no reason not to include it.

I don't know what impact disabling cinder has on the devstack stack.sh script, I've never done it.

As per RabbitMQ see above answer.